# Cat vomit, fur ball or polyp?

Tags: cats, grooming

A few years ago at the vets I mentioned that my tortie Sandy had started wretching after drinking cold water, and that her purr had become slightly raspy. They said that she might have a polyp in her throat, but that it wouldn't be a good idea to operate on it.
She's been overgrooming recently (because she hates the maincoon I have). I've included a link to a video. Would you say that this is just her coughing up a fur ball or something else? She hasn't in this video, but she does sometimes leave little bits of sick.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/xyjAp9y2uLvmRMt47

(Apologies if this is a dumb question, I've never actually seen a cat cough up a fur ball, and my other cat with a lot more fur doesn't do this)

Thanks,

Joe